# i am trying to separate out a circuit that has my basement outlets and also my septic tank aerator pump. question on best way to proceed

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, circuit

So this is made more complicated in that this circuit is tied together with another circuit through Multi branch wiring....these circuits are sharing a neutral.  The junction box with all the initial splices for both circuits is the box in question.  I see the power going into the box in a conduit.  Then its essentially chaos in there.  I wouldn't be surprised if other circuits are also using this junction box.  I can see my one little romex in question leaving the box and heading to my outlets.  I know the right away is likely to try and dig thru everything and undo the the splices for the 3 wires in my 12/2 (including ground), tie what's left back up and then use a second junction that connects the romex i just disconnected to the new romex heading back to the panel.  This would leave only my septic tank on one side of the 20 amp MBW.  and my outlets on their own new circuit.  Would it be ok to just leave the splices in the box, cut the 12/2 2 feet or so outside the junction box and cap in a second box.  then use a third box to tie my new romex run from the panel to other end of the old romex i just cut?  Its messier but then i dont have to deal much with the old box.  thanks!

Comment: The pump should be on it's own circuit.  A MBWC circuit should use /3 cable, half the circuit on red and half on black.  Usually every top of an receptacle on red or every second receptacle on red.